# How to use .NET Memory Mapped File in Linux without persisted file?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, memory-mapped-files

Using .NET (dotnet 5.0) on Linux, `MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile()` works (but does not support `mapName`), but `CreateNew()` and `CreateOrOpen()` and `OpenExisting()` throw `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Named maps are not supported.`. Since named maps are not supported, it means only persisted file-backed memory maps are supported.

Is there some way to get a memory based, non-persisted MMF in .NET on linux? Perhaps some mono library, or something else in NuGet? Or even a working example using `pinvoke`?

I would like to share memory in linux between a C# .NET application, and some other applications, possibly in C, C++, and/or python. It is desirable to use shared memory rather than sockets or pipes, because I don't want data to wait in a buffer if the consumer isn't available.

Comment: Its just not supported, enough said. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/21863, use an actual file with null for the name, example here https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles/tests/MemoryMappedFile.CrossProcess.cs#L13

Comment: @00110001 That's not helpful. I'm looking for shared memory, not file. It's definitely possible via pinvoke, but I haven't gotten it to work and haven't found an example yet. There are often solutions to this kind of thing buried in mono or nuget, etc. Hence I asked the question. Thanks.

Comment: So are you saying. Stephan Toubs comment "*named memory mapped files are not supported on Unix. You can create anonymous maps, just by passing null as the name. You can also create maps for actual files, e.g. with CreateFromFile.*" doesn't apply to you?

Comment: Are you also saying, that the test he provided for an anonymous memory mapped file is not memory mapped?

Comment: @00110001 I am saying what you linked is using a backing file. It's not just shared memory. Just because .NET core doesn't support shared memory doesn't mean you can't get shared memory in another way. (Shared memory = memory mapped file without a backing file). If you don't already know pinvoke, look it up. Anything you can do in C you can do in .NET with proper bindings. This is what mono.posix and mono.unix do, for many unix things, but not shared mem as far as I can find. That's why I put pinvoke, mono, nuget etc in the question. I just don't have a working solution yet.

Comment: @EdwardNedHarvey did you find a way to do this? I'm trying to do something similar but struggling to get a Unix file descriptor from the MemoryMappedFile handle in C#

Comment: EdwardNedHarvey and @DannyFriar - any luck getting something to work? I too am looking for a memory-backed solution on Linux using .NET.

Comment: This issue and PR may be useful https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/52854

Comment: @DannyFriar Thanks for the link. How do I use that? Do I need to pull down, change and compile the .NET libraries? Or is there an easier way to incorporate your changes into my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a way with `/dev/shm`:

> **Persistence** POSIX shared memory objects have kernel persistence: a
> shared memory object will exist until the system is shut down, or
> until all processes have unmapped the object and it has been deleted
> with shm_unlink(3)
>
> **Accessing shared memory objects via the filesystem** On Linux, shared
> memory objects are created in a (tmpfs(5)) virtual filesystem,
> normally mounted under /dev/shm.  Since Linux
> 2.6.19, Linux supports the use of access control lists (ACLs) to control the permissions of objects in the virtual filesystem.

This should work:

```
MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile("/dev/shm/test", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, null, 100000);
```

[C# (mono) Linux Memory Mapped Files - Shared Memory (multiple processes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74840766/c-sharp-mono-linux-memory-mapped-files-shared-memory-multiple-processes)